# Delay execution of protractor elementArrayFinder.map

Tags: javascript, protractor

If you call the `map` function of a protractor elementArrayFinder, it will immediately search the DOM for the elements to map them, which differs from the behavior of `$$` which waits until the child elementArrayFinder evaluation is needed to find both the original element and its descendants.

The reason I need to delay the map function execution is I want to pre-define it in a file outside my test file for the purpose of abstraction. The current attempt I have is:

```
Question.array = function(elementArrayFinder) {

  function delayedPromise(executor) {
    this.executor = executor;
  }

  delayedPromise.prototype.then = function(onFulfilled, onRejected) {
    console.log('locating elements');
    return (new Promise(this.executor)).then(onFulfilled, onRejected);
  };

  return new delayedPromise(function(resolve, reject) {
    elementArrayFinder.map(function(omniTask) {
      return new Question(omniTask);
    }).then(resolve, reject);
  });
};
```

This was working for a while, but when I restructured the test file today (not the file containing this function, this function hasn't changed in a while), JavaScript began to have a memory problem relating to this function:

```
<--- Last few GCs --->

  133580 ms: Mark-sweep 1354.3 (1421.2) -> 1354.3 (1437.2) MB, 2608.1 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  136052 ms: Mark-sweep 1354.3 (1437.2) -> 1354.3 (1437.2) MB, 2471.9 / 0.0 ms [allocation failure] [GC in old space requested].
  138829 ms: Mark-sweep 1354.3 (1437.2) -> 1355.7 (1421.2) MB, 2775.8 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].
  141436 ms: Mark-sweep 1355.7 (1421.2) -> 1357.0 (1421.2) MB, 2606.6 / 0.0 ms [last resort gc].


<--- JS stacktrace --->

==== JS stack trace =========================================

Security context: 0x13c845cfb51 <JS Object>
    1: enqueue [/Users/thasisclaus/omnistack/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:~2742] [pc=0x27de9185871b] (this=0x2b9531847931 <an EventEmitter with map 0x17526dabf9e9>,task=0x17b6b944f181 <a Deferred with map 0x17526dac0649>)
    2: addCallback_ [/Users/thasisclaus/omnistack/node_modules/selenium-webdriver/lib/promise.js:~1328] [pc=0x27de919c1a75] (this=0x17b6b944eeb9 <a ManagedPro...

FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
 1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
 2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 5: v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::TypeFeedbackMetadata> v8::internal::TypeFeedbackMetadata::New<v8::internal::FeedbackVectorSpec>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::FeedbackVectorSpec const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 6: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::EnsureFeedbackVector(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 7: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GenerateBaselineCode(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 8: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GetUnoptimizedCodeCommon(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
 9: v8::internal::Compiler::Compile(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ClearExceptionFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
10: v8::internal::Accessors::FunctionLengthGetter(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
11: v8::internal::PropertyCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&), v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
12: v8::internal::Object::GetPropertyWithAccessor(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
13: v8::internal::Object::GetProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
14: v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_FunctionPrototypeBind(v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::BuiltinArguments<(v8::internal::BuiltinExtraArguments)0>, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
15: v8::internal::Builtin_FunctionPrototypeBind(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
16: 0x27de909092a7
17: 0x27de9185871b
18: 0x27de919c1a75
19: 0x27de919c202c
20: 0x27de912d1b27
21: 0x27de90909895
22: 0x27de912dee53
>> FATAL ERROR: CALL_AND_RETRY_LAST Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
>>  1: node::Abort() [/usr/local/bin/node]
>>  2: node::FatalException(v8::Isolate*, v8::Local<v8::Value>, v8::Local<v8::Message>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>>  3: v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(char const*, bool) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>>  4: v8::internal::Factory::NewFixedArray(int, v8::internal::PretenureFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>>  5: v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::TypeFeedbackMetadata> v8::internal::TypeFeedbackMetadata::New<v8::internal::FeedbackVectorSpec>(v8::internal::Isolate*, v8::internal::FeedbackVectorSpec const*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>>  6: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::EnsureFeedbackVector(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>>  7: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GenerateBaselineCode(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>>  8: v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::GetUnoptimizedCodeCommon(v8::internal::CompilationInfo*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>>  9: v8::internal::Compiler::Compile(v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::JSFunction>, v8::internal::Compiler::ClearExceptionFlag) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>> 10: v8::internal::Accessors::FunctionLengthGetter(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>> 11: v8::internal::PropertyCallbackArguments::Call(void (*)(v8::Local<v8::Name>, v8::PropertyCallbackInfo<v8::Value> const&), v8::internal::Handle<v8::internal::Name>) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>> 12: v8::internal::Object::GetPropertyWithAccessor(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>> 13: v8::internal::Object::GetProperty(v8::internal::LookupIterator*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>> 14: v8::internal::Builtin_Impl_FunctionPrototypeBind(v8::internal::(anonymous namespace)::BuiltinArguments<(v8::internal::BuiltinExtraArguments)0>, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>> 15: v8::internal::Builtin_FunctionPrototypeBind(int, v8::internal::Object**, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/usr/local/bin/node]
>> 16: 0x27de909092a7
>> 17: 0x27de9185871b
>> 18: 0x27de919c1a75
>> 19: 0x27de919c202c
>> 20: 0x27de912d1b27
>> 21: 0x27de90909895
>> 22: 0x27de912dee53
```

The context in the test file that I changed today is:

```
fit('Should have the right number of assignment questions initially', function(done) {
      var done = browserHelper.strictDone(done),
          self = this;

      self.communityQuestions = self.myQuestions = [];

      console.log(self.assignmentQuestions.length, self.communityQuestions.length, self.myQuestions.length)

      assignmentPage.assignmentQuestions.then(function(assignmentQuestions) {
        expect(assignmentQuestions.length).toEqual(self.assignmentQuestions.length);

        assignmentPage.communityQuestionsTab.click();

        assignmentPage.communityQuestions.then(function(communityQuestions) {
          expect(communityQuestions.length).toEqual(self.communityQuestions.length);

          assignmentPage.myQuestionsTab.click();

          assignmentPage.myQuestions.then(function(myQuestions) {
            console.log(myQuestions);

            expect(myQuestions.length).toEqual(self.myQuestions.length);

            done();
          });
        });
      });
    });
```

I don't know if the error is actually caused by the function or some outside change that the function happens to encounter. Regardless, I think there is probably a better way to delay the map function, most likely by interacting with Protractor's control flow directly.

Comment: We've been just putting maps, filters and other things into page object functions to workaround similar situations..

Comment: As in the page object file contain functions that return the map promise like `ageObject.getProperty = function() {return pageObject.previouslyDefinedElementArrayFinder.map(/* args */)}` rather than doing something like `pageObject.property = pageObject.previouslyDefinedElementArrayFinder.map(/* args */)`?

Answer (score 1):

Even though I wasn't returning elements with maps (instead I was returning objects constructed from elements), I think this is related to this error in which map hangs: https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/2227

To work around it, I just changed my `map` to a `reduce` and changed the function passed accordingly, which worked perfectly.

I'm pretty certain `map` is one of the less updated elementArrayFinder iterating functions since unlike `reduce` and lodash functions, `map` does not have the last argument being the collection, and thus follows an older convention.